# Git - Does git store pasword in $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig; trying to find all locations where git stores password in both Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu, github

I am trying to see if `git` is storing my credentials, especially the password, for both Windows and Ubuntu. I want to make sure my credentials will no longer be available in two particular systems.

I have looked into `config` file inside the repository directory and didn't find any credentials.

I also looked into `.gitconfig` file in both Windows (under `C:\Users\$USER\`) and Ubuntu (under `$HOME`). This file contained my username and email.

I am trying to find the location of '/etc/gitconfig' file mentioned in this [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) . However, I couldn't do so for both Windows and Ubuntu. For Windows, I checked the `etc` folder inside installation folder and it had no `gitconfig`. I also checked the `config` file inside 'C:\ProgramData\Git', but it had no credentials stored in it. However, I discovered that Windows had a file called `.github` next to `.gitconfig`, which contained my username and password. Is this file equivalent or replacement for '/etc/gitconfig' ? Where can I see it's Ubuntu counterpart?

What files to delete or how can I make sure that no one will be able to use my git account in both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: Git has nothing to do with passwords AFAIK.

Comment: But I did find the password in `.github` file in windows, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: It's not done by Git. Look for other tools you are using.

Comment: I see. So, is this file corresponding to `git-credential-store`?

Comment: To expand on @0andriy's comment: Git generally does not store credentials. It runs what it calls a *credential helper* program. The exact form of program is (a) OS-dependent and (b) usually highly configurable. There is a good help page [on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) that covers OS X, Windows, and Linux. Git does have `git-credential-store`, but it is best to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Interesting, yes, it's possible it does that. @torek, thanks!

Comment: I don't remember using or executing any command related to `credential helper` or `git-credential-store`. I think today is the first time I heard of them. But I have used GitHub Desktop. I guess that was the reason behind `.github` file.

Comment: One other point that may be of general use: if you are concerned about what git has stored in various configuration files, you can run `git config --list --show-origin` and look for the information in question.  If it's there, you'll be given the path to the config file that contains it.  As for the password question, I'll just say on Windows if your git version is fairly current there's a good chance it ties into the Windows credential store (accessible via Control Panel). This is likely so if you entered the name/pw via a pop-up instead of prompt

Comment: (In the case of current git for windows, you wouldn't necessarily have had to run/configure anything or even know there was such a thing as credential helper; modern Git for Windows distribution configures its use (as needed) by default)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Thank you for the reply. I checked credential store and it had git listed under Generic Credentials. So that resolves the issue with `.github` file, I guess.

Comment: So, if I haven't used `git-credential-store` in Windows or Ubuntu, I don't have to worry since `credential helper` will keep the password in the cache only for a very limited time. Is that right?

Comment: It does depend on which helper was used. The helpers used by default on older Windows versions used a time-based cache I believe, but for the credentials you found under Generic Credentials in the windows credential store, if you're done with them you should delete them from the vault manually.

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't answer your original question, but it does answer the question in your second sentence "I want to make sure my credentials will no longer be available in two particular systems.". While after much searching you could be **close to certain** that your credentials were no longer on the machine, you couldn't be completely certain.

I suggest simply changing your password on github or any other service you want to protect. Then it doesn't matter what is left on the machine.